# How to shuffle just one column of table/list?

Tags: list-manipulation, random

I have a list in form {{X1,Y1,type},....{Xn,Yn,type}}. X and Y are coordinates and type is a number between 1 to 15, the length of the list is 12000, so I can not upload the data here. I need to keep (X,Y) fixed and randomize (shuffle) the third column (type) to create another list. How can I do that? Also, How can I create many (over 100) different version of shuffled list?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Tip: Even if you can not share the list with 12000 entries, you could still show the structure with made up content for N=3 or something, so we get a better idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 5):

```
data = Join[Array[x, {10, 2}], List /@ Array[z, {10}], 2];

MatrixForm @ data
```

[image]

You can use [`SubsetMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubsetMap.html) + [`RandomSample`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomSample.html):

```
SeedRandom[1];
data2 = SubsetMap[RandomSample, {All, 3}] @ data;

MatrixForm @ data2
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use in-place part assignment to replace the third column `data`:

```
SeedRandom[1];
data[[All, 3]] = RandomSample[data[[All, 3]]];

MatrixForm @ data
```

[image]

**Update:** ***"How can I create too many (over 100) different version of shuffled list?"***

```
n = 5; (* use n = 100 in your case *)

SeedRandom[1];

datasets = Join[data[[All, ;; 2]], List /@ #, 2] & /@ 
   Table[RandomSample[data[[All, 3]]], n];

MatrixForm /@ datasets
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A variation using `MapThread`:

Create the subscript array of the required length and then use MapThread:

```
pts = Transpose@{Range[10], Range[10], RandomSample[Range[10]]}
MapThread[Part, {{x, y, z}, #}] & /@ pts
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 x[[1]] & y[[1]] & z[[9]] \\
 x[[2]] & y[[2]] & z[[2]] \\
 x[[3]] & y[[3]] & z[[7]] \\
 x[[4]] & y[[4]] & z[[6]] \\
 x[[5]] & y[[5]] & z[[4]] \\
 x[[6]] & y[[6]] & z[[3]] \\
 x[[7]] & y[[7]] & z[[10]] \\
 x[[8]] & y[[8]] & z[[1]] \\
 x[[9]] & y[[9]] & z[[5]] \\
 x[[10]] & y[[10]] & z[[8]] \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

which you can weave further into your solution using the excellent answer by @kglr.

Storing an array of random permuted data beforehand does not offer many advantages for computation, but it may be required for presentation purposes.

Answer (score 3):

```
arr=Array[a, {10, 3}];

Join[arr[[All,1;;2]],Transpose[{RandomSample[arr[[All,3]]]}],2]//TeXForm
```

$$\left(
             \begin{array}{ccc}
              a(1,1) & a(1,2) & a(7,3) \\
              a(2,1) & a(2,2) & a(2,3) \\
              a(3,1) & a(3,2) & a(8,3) \\
              a(4,1) & a(4,2) & a(9,3) \\
              a(5,1) & a(5,2) & a(6,3) \\
              a(6,1) & a(6,2) & a(1,3) \\
              a(7,1) & a(7,2) & a(10,3) \\
              a(8,1) & a(8,2) & a(3,3) \\
              a(9,1) & a(9,2) & a(5,3) \\
              a(10,1) & a(10,2) & a(4,3) \\
             \end{array}
             \right)
$$

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[0];

x = Array[a, {5, 3}];
```

Using `MapThread` with `Append`

```
MapThread[Append, {x[[All, 1 ;; 2]], RandomSample @ x[[All, 3]]}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Using `MapAt` with double `Transpose`

```
MapAt[RandomSample, Transpose @ x, 3] // Transpose // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[0];

x = Array[a, {5, 3}];
```

---

Grabbing the @eldo's example, a variant using `TakeList` is the following:

```
Join @@@ Thread[MapAt[List /@ RandomSample[x[[All, 3]]] &, 
Thread[TakeList[#, {2, 1}] & /@ x], {2}]] // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  a(1,1) & a(1,2) & a(4,3) \\
>  a(2,1) & a(2,2) & a(2,3) \\
>  a(3,1) & a(3,2) & a(5,3) \\
>  a(4,1) & a(4,2) & a(1,3) \\
>  a(5,1) & a(5,2) & a(3,3) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$